# Xterm display not showing properly while executing java program in linux

Tags: java, linux, xterm

I am facing one issue while interacting with linux using java code.
My need is to execute java program in linux environment which will open xterm and the execution will show there.

The code I am using :

```
 try {
     Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
     String myScript = "/usr/bin/ls";
     String[] cmdArray = {"xterm", "-e", myScript + " ; le_exec"};
     r.exec(cmdArray);
 } catch (InterruptedException ex){
   ex.printStackTrace();
 } catch (IOException ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
 }
```

The XTERM is opening on running the java program but is closing on its own and I am not able to see what went on for display in XTERM. As far as I know " ; le_exec" this is used for xterm to remain open unless key enter is not pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Put `$SHELL` at the end of your script to prevent closing xterm after script execution.

Comment: thanks its working fine , however I am inquisitive about one more thing that what will be cmd i passed in runtime process to have change my path and after that execute the cmd like mkdir... I know this is possible by using a shell script but I do not prefer to go for that for just a mkdir operation. Is there any work out?